# Error: unexpected string constant in "curl

Tags: r, web-scraping, curl

I am following the instructions on this website (https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md) to learn how to use the OSM (Open Street Maps) API.

I tried following some of the examples on this website - many of the examples are in the following format:

```
library(Rcurl)
library(osmdata)

# Query on Berlin excluding the usage of motorways:
curl 'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?exclude=motorway'
```

But this is always returning the same error:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "curl 'http://router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037?number=3&bearings=0,20'"
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way?

```
remotes::install_github("riatelab/osrm")

route2 <-  osrmRoute(src = c(13.412, 52.502),
                     dst = c(13.454, 52.592), osrm.profile = "car")

route2$distance
```

Comment: I can't tell if this is an answer or a comment/follow-up on your question; the question mark makes things confusing. If it's an answer, please expand and then accept this as the solution (it's fine answering your own questions). If it's a comment/follow-up, this should go in your main post.

Comment: @ mauritis evers:  thank you! I wasn't sure if I fixed this problem, hence the question mark. I can remove it if needed. thank you!